# How to play the movie without showing it in the beginning on PowerPoint?

Tags: video, microsoft-powerpoint, animation

When I am presenting at a conference, the control panel can only play forward or backward, without clicking the mouse cursor to a particular point. So if I have a movie to play, I have to make sure it can be played under a "forward" button.

The "Animation" property for a movie has additional "Media" options, while a picture does not have.
[image]

If the "Play" option is selected, the movie object will be displayed in the beginning of the slide show (which is bad), and be played under a "forward".

If an "Entrance" option is selected (e.g. "Float In"), the movie object will not be shown in the beginning (which is good), but will not be played under a "forward" (which is bad).

So is there a way that the movie object is not displayed when the slide show starts, but could be displayed AND played under "forward"?

I can of course use a white box to cover the movie object then hide it afterwards. But is there a more efficient way?

I am using Win10, Office 365.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select the video and add the "Appear" event to it

[image]

2. Then add the "Play" event

[image]

Both events should be one below the other in your time line.

3. Right-click on the bottom one and select "Start with previous"

[image]

Comment: super good! This is exactly what I want. I did not realise that one object can have more than one animation!